# Date in to UTC format Java

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have a string like this `2013-10-22T01:37:56`. I Need to change this string into UTC Date format like this `MM/dd/yyyy KK:mm:ss a`. I have tried some code but it is not returning the UTC datetime.

My code is

```
        String[] time = itsAlarmDttm.split("T");
        String aFormatDate = time[0]+ " "+time[1];
        String aRevisedDate = null;
        try {
            final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            final Date dateObj = sdf.parse(aFormatDate);
            aRevisedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy KK:mm:ss a").format(dateObj);
            System.out.println(aRevisedDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            itsLogger.error("Error occured in Parsing the Data Time Object:  " +e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            itsLogger.error("Error occured in Data Time Objecct:  " +e.getMessage());
        }
```

I am getting the output is `MM/dd/yyyy KK:mm:ss a` format. But Not UTC time format.
How to solve this issue?

Comment: what is it returning?

Comment: UTC is not a specific date format but something like a time zone.

Comment: do you want to return what time is it in UTC time zone?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to format your date with the `Z` or `z` timezone flags:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy KK:mm:ss a Z").format(dateObj);
```

Answer (score 34):

Try this... Worked for me and printed `10/22/2013 01:37:56 AM` Ofcourse this is your code only with little modifications.

```
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));   // This line converts the given date into UTC time zone
final java.util.Date dateObj = sdf.parse("2013-10-22T01:37:56");

aRevisedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy KK:mm:ss a").format(dateObj);
System.out.println(aRevisedDate);
```

Comment: sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); -- this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: The example is chaotic. "sdf.setTimeZone(...)" comes after "sdf.parse(...)". And "format(dateObj)" uses a new SimpleDateFormat. So "setTimeZone" has no effect on anything here. It is the correct hint though.

Answer (score 10):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" );
// or SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "MM/dd/yyyy KK:mm:ss a Z" );
sdf.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "UTC" ) );
System.out.println( sdf.format( new Date() ) );
```

Answer (score 8):

## What Time Zones?

No where in your question do you mention [time zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). What time zone is implied that input string? What time zone do you want for your output? And, [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) is a time zone (or lack thereof depending on your mindset) *not a string format*.

## ISO 8601

Your input string is in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, except that it lacks an [offset from UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC).

## Joda-Time

Here is some example code in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 to show you how to handle time zones. Joda-Time has built-in default [formatters](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for parsing and generating String representations of date-time values.

```
String input = "2013-10-22T01:37:56";
DateTime dateTimeUtc = new DateTime( input, DateTimeZone.UTC );
DateTime dateTimeMontréal = dateTimeUtc.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
String output = dateTimeMontréal.toString();
```

As for generating string representations in other formats, search StackOverflow for "Joda format".

Answer (score 4):

### java.time

It’s about time someone provides the modern answer. The modern solution uses java.time, the modern Java date and time API. The classes `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` used in the question and in a couple of the other answers are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. `TimeZone` is poorly designed to. I recommend you avoid those.

```
    ZoneId utc = ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC");
    DateTimeFormatter targetFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
            "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a zzz", Locale.ENGLISH);

    String itsAlarmDttm = "2013-10-22T01:37:56";
    ZonedDateTime utcDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(itsAlarmDttm)
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .withZoneSameInstant(utc);
    String formatterUtcDateTime = utcDateTime.format(targetFormatter);
    System.out.println(formatterUtcDateTime);
```

When running in my time zone, Europe/Copenhagen, the output is:

> 10/21/2013 11:37:56 PM UTC

I have assumed that the string you got was in the default time zone of your JVM, a fragile assumption since that default setting can be changed at any time from another part of your program or another programming running in the same JVM. If you can, instead specify time zone explicitly, for example `ZoneId.of("Europe/Podgorica")` or `ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")`.

I am exploiting the fact that you string is in ISO 8601 format, the format the the modern classes parse as their default, that is, without any explicit formatter.

I am using a `ZonedDateTime` for the result date-time because it allows us to format it with `UTC` in the formatted string to eliminate any and all doubt. For other purposes one would typically have wanted an `OffsetDateTime` or an `Instant` instead.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)