# How to convert the date and time in any timezone in the Gmail to the UTC format using java

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

I want to convert the dates which are available in the mail headers in timezones like PST or PDT to the UTC format using java.

For example:

**Tue, 21 Apr 2015 07:12:18 -0700 (PDT).** This is the date which will be in the string variable. I want to convert this date into the UTC format.This date is not the current system date. Please suggest me the solution of the problem in java.

Comment: Please show, what you have so far! ..also consider reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/308689/592355) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20238531/592355) answers..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the current date and time in UTC or GMT in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the [MimeMessage](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html) [getSentDate](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getSentDate()) or [getReceivedDate](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getReceivedDate()) methods, you'll get a [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object that's already properly converted.  You just need to format and display the date however you want, e.g., using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 1):

## Obsolete format

Your example data is odd. As I recall the old email standards use [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) or [RFC 822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt). Your format is similar, but missing the colon between hour and minute of the offset, and has extraneous parens around the pseudo-zone.

Be aware that such formats are obsolete. They are difficult to parse by machine. And they assume English language and particular cultural norms. Modern protocols adopted [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats instead. The ISO 8601 formats are used by default in the *java.time* classes.

## *java.time*

If you really must parse text in that specific format, define a `DateTimeFormatter` to match its formatting pattern.

```
String input = "Tue, 21 Apr 2015 07:12:18 -0700 (PDT)";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE, dd MMM uuuu HH:mm:ss XXXX '('z')'" ).withLocale( Locale.US );
```

Parse as a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2015-04-21T07:12:18-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]

Note that `PDT` is not a real time zone names. Never use these 2-4 letter pseudo-zones. [Real time zones](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjv8K_Dur3lAhVLHDQIHYyQArgQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FList_of_tz_database_time_zones&usg=AOvVaw1ibswR3BxTVUI29KBQKNBH) have a name in `Continent/Region` format such as `America/Los_Angeles`.

Comment: I think I’d consider the offset more reliable than the three-letter time zone abbreviaiton and therefore parse into an `OffsetDateTIme` rather then a `ZonedDateTime`. There are pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

For that conversion, you will need a good time library that takes into consideration daylight saving time, etc. A great one for java is [Joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). 
The library permits a variety of formatting options, for both inputs and outputs, to solve your problem. Look at the documentation for samples.

Comment: FYI: The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), its creator, [Stephen Colebourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen), having gone on to lead [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) defining the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8+. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).